# Error while reading from local JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript. My JavaScript (script.js) reads from a JSON file as shown below. The script reads without using JQuery. I followed [THIS](http://www.askyb.com/javascript/load-json-file-locally-by-js-without-jquery/) site for reference.

```
function readJSON() {
  var LatLongData = JSON.parse(data);
  var LatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(LatLongData[0]);
}
```

The JSON file (data.json), stored in the same location as the JavaScript is as below:

```
{ "data": 
[
    {"latitude" : "40.10246648", "longitude" : "-83.14877599"}
]
}
```

The html file is as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&sensor=true"></script>
<body onload="readJSON()">
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
```

I get 2 errors (both in chrome as well as Firebug) on the JSON file format. However, I verified online (http://jsonlint.com/) that the JSON file is of the right format. The errors I get are:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement { "data":

ReferenceError: data is not defined  ---> var LatLongData = JSON.parse(data);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: prepend "data=" to your 'json' file and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read the json like that. First of all you should not include it via <script> tag. You need to get the json via ajax request. I'll suggest to check the jQuery's getJSON method:

```
$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
   // now you can read the data
   var LatLongData = data;
   var LatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(LatLongData[0]);
});
```

What you are doing is to include the json as javascript file. That's why you got that error. Second, your *readJSON* uses *data* variable which is actually never defined.

Comment: But I am reading the JSON from a file. Do I still need to use ajax?

Comment: Ajax is the way to load files via javascript. It's a http request to the file. You could do the same thing via PHP or some other server-side technology, but this should happen before to show the page.

Answer (score 1):

You included this Json

```
{ "data": 
[
    {"latitude" : "40.10246648", "longitude" : "-83.14877599"}
]
}
```

but the code is expecting a **variable** called data, 
if you pay attention to the example in the link in their "json" file they are "cheating" , it's not pure JSON as is declaring a global variable, containing a string. That string is the json.
So if you go ahead following those practice you should have a "json" file.

with

```
var data = '[ {"latitude" : "40.10246648", "longitude" : "-83.14877599"}]'
```

but I suggest you to follow Krasimir's answer.